# Drawing simple shapes, which is more efficient: Shaprenderer or SpriteBatch?

Tags: opengl, libgdx, vector-graphics, raster-graphics

In my game, I have about 50 filled-circles with different size and different color distributed full screen, and they continuously resize themselves, creating animation. I'm currently using `Shaperenderer` to render all of them. This way, all the circles look crisp but it seems like the performance is not very good. Should I make a circle sprite and then render all of them using `SpriteBatch` instead of `Shaperenderer`? Will the performance be improved by doing that?

Comment: Try both and time them. Make sure to time *only* the rendering (and not, for example, constructing the sprites). Run multiple times, to prevent warming up/caching issues.

Comment: This depends on number of circles and how big they are on screen. But if they are very big at all, you will probably have a fill rate problem using sprites. In that case, first make sure you have depth testing turned on. If that isn't it, maybe your current slow down is too many draw calls and you need to find a way to batch them into a single call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, yes, the `SpriteBatch` API is more optimized than the `ShapeRenderer` API in Libgdx.  `ShapeRenderer` is designed for debug overlays and for being easy to use.  But, it depends on the specifics of how you use the APIs, too.

The `ShapeRenderer` API assumes your viewport is mapped to pixel units.  It determines the number of vertices to use in the circle based on a rough guess.  You may be creating too many vertices for each circle (and you may be able to improve the performance without sacrificing fidelity by reducing the number of vertices computed).

For any specific case though, it makes sense to profile your code and see where the time is actually being spent before optimizing.